# Multiple Alarms fired as one in an intent (List View)

Tags: android, listview, alarms

Since no one answered my previous question about multiple alarm at the same time in android ([Multiple alarms at the same time in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402229/multiple-alarms-at-the-same-time-in-android)), I came up with another solution. The problem is how to start this approach.

Here's what I have in mind. My application has a Broadcast Receiver running on background which checks if the current time is equal to the alarm time stored in the database, If yes-- it fires a service which starts an intent. (For single alarms)

For multiple alarms at the same time, I'm confused on how to check if there is more than alarm set on the same time and how to store the those alarms and to fire them as one intent listed in a listview.

Any ideas how?

---

Hi All,

The solution I came up to achieve this is set a delay small enough to gather all intents (e.g: More than one alarm). Before it fires the notification so that it will look like all are fired at the same time :)